# Powerapps DropDown Control issues : While Populating drop down input control items with text/records/list/DataRows from Azure function

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps, powerapps

**Agenda:** We are trying to display our data fetched from *SQL* in drop down list ,But instead of giving directly we are using *"Azure Functions"* which can help retrieve data from SQL via *Key Vault*

**Issue:** Powerapps DropDown/ListBox control are not able to understand the output given by Azure function. We tried to render outputs from Azure Functions i.e. string/text/records/list/DataRows

**Error:**

> the property expects table values but this rule produces incompatible
>   text values

**What we did:**

1. Created Azure Function(Gave all needed access such as managed service identity, app addition to AAD etc.)(Tested the function, we get expected output)
2. Created API with swagger 2.0
3. Created a Custom powerapp connector with the above OpenAPI file(Connector works fine)
4. We invoke the function from the Powerapp canvas like this 
   `MCFAzureFunction.RunThis(Button1.Pressed)`

**Help:** Let us know how best we can push the response data fromazure function to powerapp dropdown or listbox control. or we are doing/missing something

**Code:**

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault;
using Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace MCFuncApp
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        private static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        private static string BuildConnString(string secret, string dbCatalog)
        {
            return ("Server=********** Timeout=30;");
        }

        private static string DataTableToJSON(DataTable table)
        {
            string JSONString = string.Empty;
            JSONString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(table);
            return JSONString;
        }

        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)]HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
        {

            log.Info("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            // parse query parameter
            string name = req.GetQueryNameValuePairs()
                .FirstOrDefault(q => string.Compare(q.Key, "name", true) == 0)
                .Value;

            if (name == null)
            {
                // Get request body
                dynamic data = await req.Content.ReadAsAsync<object>();
                name = data?.name;
            }

            string exampleSecret = "Secret";
            string qResponse = "";

            if(name != null)
            {   // "https://********"
                string vaultBaseUrl = "*********";
                var azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
                var kvClient = new KeyVaultClient(new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(azureServiceTokenProvider.KeyVaultTokenCallback), client);
                var secret = (await kvClient.GetSecretAsync(vaultBaseUrl)).Value;
                var connString = BuildConnString(secret, "*****");

                string query = "*********";

                var dt = new DataTable();
                using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, connString))
                {
                    da.Fill(dt);
                }

                qResponse = DataTableToJSON(dt);                
            }


            return name == null
                ? req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body")
                : req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, qResponse, "application/json");
        }
    }
}
```

*Thanks in Advance !*

Comment: What does the function return actually other than the expected value?

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue might be related to the structure of the **JSON** content the **Azure Function** returns.

A supported structure should look something like:

```
Table({ Text: "Item 1", Val: 1 }, { Text: "Item 2", Val: 2 }, { Text: "Item 3", Val: 3 })
```

You might need to serialize the returned rows manually, as the `DataRow` class contains much more information than what you need, and concatenate the end result using a `StringBuilder` before passing it back as the response's content.

Hope it helps.